# Progress Bar Bootstrap - Mobile & Desktop

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using vertical progress bar which works fine on desktop but I want to change back to horizontal on mobile which is also working fine by removing "progress-bar-vertical" class from below div only on mobile.

```
<div class="progress progress-bar-vertical">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
            aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height:90%" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Center">
    </div>
</div>
```

But I need to change inline css "width:90%" on the desktop to "height:90%" on mobile. How can I do this.

Comment: using media queries. `@media screen and (max-width:480px){yourElement{height:90% // and other styles you need in mobile view }}`

Comment: There are many progress bars, not with same value. Values are from DB.

Comment: You can read values from your database and assign it to JavaScript table. Then you can use that values to change height and width on certain breakpoints in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can add data-attribute to your HTML and process that through jQuery using the code below:

```
var resizeTimeout = false;
$(window).resize(function() {
  if (resizeTimeout) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    //do something, window hasn't changed size in 500ms
    // Get window size and process your html
    if ($(window).width() < 480)
      $('.screen').text('Mobile');
    else
      $('.screen').text('Desktop');
  }, 200);
});
$(window).resize();
```

and JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r3nkkjto/1/

Comment: Why you are using ResizeTimeout?

Comment: Because resize event is triggered many times while dragging and in most cases you want the action to occur when the user releases the mouse (stops dragging the browsers frame).

Answer (score 0):

You can just make visible the vertical bar on desktop / hidden on other devices and horizontal bar visible on mobile / hidden on other devices.

For Desktop:

```
class = ".visible-md-* .visible-lg-*"
```

For mobile:

```
.visible-xs-*
```

For tablets:

```
.visible-sm-*
```

You will set the whole div or navbar or whatever for the desktop with the prefered class and then you set the div or navbar you want to be visible on mobile with the appropriate class.

Comment: It will be duplicate then for mobile its separate and desktop separate div

Comment: Exaclty, there will be two divs one for each device you want to be visible on. It will be a duplicate-like code but it won't appear duplicate on your page.

Comment: I don't think it's hardcoded at all, you will just set the divs at the proper classes, you can check it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) . It's simple and works perfect for what you are asking. You should give it a try, i am sure it will help you.

Comment: I know this way but its a repetitive coding.

Comment: You can also make a desktop version and a mobile version of your page and call the page you want based on the device you are using. Keep in mind when going through javascript for many things you are making a call after a call every time, which will lead you to a call pyramid. That means repetitive code, although it's not in the way you mean it, it's not the bad option sometimes. I still believe it's a very good way to go based on what you are asking.